# Anybody found a sample that uses windows authentication with working rolemanager in SL4 with RIA?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria

All the sample I come across are for forms authentication. I did manage to authenticate using windows, but the list of roles returned in the authenticated user is always empty.

In SL3 and previous version of RIA, user roles were populated with active directory security groups (worked for me). Now in SL4 it no more works.

Answer (score 2):

you need the following in your web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```